# How to revert repository to commit

Tags: git

I pushed a commit to the repo, and now the master repo is messed up
and I want to revert master to commit a) which happened a while ago.

I can't modify the master repo directly so I have to create a pr to modify it.
How can I revert master to the old commit a)?

I've tried

```
git checkout -b revertbranch
git reset HEAD --hard a
git add .
git commit -m "revert"
git push
```

However, when I try to open a pull request,
I get a message on github that says no files are changed.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
git checkout branch_x
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -f "message"
```